# how to use styled components to style the printing of a component?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, styled-components

I am trying to control the size/orientation when printing a component using styled-components. My question is: how can I use the @page CSS at-rule, or another method to style the printing component, with styled components?

CSS @page documentation:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@page

I have tried:

```
const PrintSchedulesContainer = styled.div`
  display: none;
  @media print and (min-width: 480px) {
    padding: none;
    margin: none;
  }
`;
```

And:

```
const PrintSchedulesContainer = styled.div`
  display: none;
  @page {
    size: landscape;
  }
`;
```

Comment: change the title to a property one that describes your question

Answer (score 4):

You can't target a single component to print.
You need to hide the other elements in order your component to be the only one printed.

[**@page**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@page) works only for changing printing rules.
[**@media print**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@media#Examples) let you define other class styles as well just like @media screen.

You can use **@media print** inside a wrapper styled component, making it fullscreen, fixed with a white background.

Example:

```
const PrintableBodyWrapper = styled.div`
  @media print {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    background-color: white;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
  }
`;

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
        <PrintableBodyWrapper>
          <div style={{ width: 100, height: 100, background: "grey" }}>
            I will be printed
          </div>
        </PrintableBodyWrapper>
    </div>
  );
}
```

To change print rules you need to add the @page into a [global style](https://www.styled-components.com/docs/api#createglobalstyle) and render the global style component.

```
import styled, { createGlobalStyle } from "styled-components";

const GlobalStyle = createGlobalStyle`
  @page {
    size: landscape;
    margin: 5cm;
`;

const PrintableBodyWrapper = styled.div`
  @media print {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    background-color: black;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
  }
`;

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
        <GlobalStyle />
        <PrintableBodyWrapper>
          <div style={{ width: 100, height: 100, background: "grey" }}>
            I will be printed
          </div>
        </PrintableBodyWrapper>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: makes sense, but I am trying to target a specific component. for example, i have a header and body. i just want to print the body, without the header

Comment: Ok I updated my answer again. I'm using media print with a class, You can't print a single component so you need to hide somehow the other elements. Above I'm using display fixed for this reason.

Comment: It was weird that media print wasn't working inside a styled component for me so I gave it a try today with a clean mind and it works. I updated my answer to be simple and clean. Furthermore you can read more about media print as a css rule. It will work the same way in styled components as it works in any css style.

Comment: Be cautious with `fixed`, it can prevent printing multiple pages.

Comment: Package that allows you to target an individual component to print (disclaimer: I am the maintainer for the package): https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-to-print